# I want to create a mandatory column in excel depending upon the value of other column

Tags: excel

I have a column "status" and other column "Reschedule date" in my excel, If the status is rescheduled, I want a pop up ( or some kind a note ) to fill the reschedule date column.

I am new to vb and macros. Please let me know the simplest way to do that.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to hilight the data column when Status = "Rescheduled"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your requirement but picking on `or some kind a note` might something like this suit?:

[image: SO21841544 example]

which you can arrange to be displayed any time a cell in a selected range (column?) is even selected by applying Data Validation, Input Message, check Show input message when cell is selected, adding `WARNING` as Title: and `Please remember to fill the reschedule date column if you change the status!` as Input message: